# Modify tabular to Stretch First Column Instead of Last Column if Needed

Tags: tables, multicolumn, column-width

It appears that if the total widths of the columns is insufficient, `tabular` stretches the *last* column. In the following image note that the last column is stretched due to the heading being wide.

[image]

#### Question:

Is there a simple way to change this default to stretch the *first* column instead?

#### Notes:

- These tables are automatically generated and can have a maximum of 18 columns.  Thus, the `l*{17}{c}` tabular specification.
- One way for me to resolve this problem would be to specify the width of the first column, but seems to me that there must be a better way.  I would prefer not to have to make the first column wider than it needs to be.

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\def\NumberOfColumns{4}%

\newcommand*{\BuildTable}[1]{%
    %% #1 = Title
    \begin{tabular}{l*{17}{c}}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{\NumberOfColumns}{c}{{#1}} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){1-4}
        Heading & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
        \cmidrule(lr){1-1}
        \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
        \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
        \cmidrule(lr){4-4}
        Label & a & b & c \\
        Label & a & b & c \\
        Label & a & b & c \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
}%

\begin{document}
\BuildTable{Narrow Title}
\quad
\BuildTable{Some Title That is Wide}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use the `tblr` environment from `tabularray` package, you can specify the option `hspan=even` to evenly stretch all columns.

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\def\NumberOfColumns{4}%

\begin{document}

    normal \verb|tblr| \smallskip
    
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={l*{3}{c}}}
        \toprule
        \SetCell[c=\NumberOfColumns]{c} Some Title That is Wide \\
        \cmidrule[lr]{1-4}
        Heading & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
        \cmidrule[lr]{1-1}
        \cmidrule[lr]{2-2}
        \cmidrule[lr]{3-3}
        \cmidrule[lr]{4-4}
        Label & a & b & c \\
        Label & a & b & c \\
        Label & a & b & c \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
    \bigskip
    
    with \verb|hspan=even| \smallskip
    
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={l*{3}{c}},hspan=even}
        \toprule
        \SetCell[c=\NumberOfColumns]{c} Some Title That is Wide \\
        \cmidrule[lr]{1-4}
        Heading & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
        \cmidrule[lr]{1-1}
        \cmidrule[lr]{2-2}
        \cmidrule[lr]{3-3}
        \cmidrule[lr]{4-4}
        Label & a & b & c \\
        Label & a & b & c \\
        Label & a & b & c \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}

    \bigskip
    
    with \verb|booktabs| spacing \smallskip
    
    \begin{booktabs}{colspec={l*{3}{c}},hspan=even}
        \toprule
        \SetCell[c=\NumberOfColumns]{c} Some Title That is Wide \\
        \cmidrule[lr]{1-4}
        Heading & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
        \cmidrule[lr]{1-1}
        \cmidrule[lr]{2-2}
        \cmidrule[lr]{3-3}
        \cmidrule[lr]{4-4}
        Label & a & b & c \\
        Label & a & b & c \\
        Label & a & b & c \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{booktabs}
\end{document}
```

The `tblr` environment has more vertical spacing by default. If you would like to keep the `booktabs` spacing, use the `booktabs` environment provided by `tabularray` package, which behaves the same as a regular `tabular` regarding the spacing.

Comment: Looks like this requires an update to the TeXLive 2021 packages so can't test it right now, but does look promising.

Comment: @PeterGrill with `tabularray` package, you also don't need to worry about column numbers, since you can write `columns={c}, column{1}={l}`.